# Good realtime display perfomance and input processing for .NET desktop application approach

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, gdi+

I am tasked to write a .NET application that displays a slide-show with some information (words or images) and when the user sees certain items, s/he must immediately press space and the time of the key press must be recorded. The items will be displayed one after the other, for about 50ms. I need then to evaluate the difference between the timestamp of the keypress and and the one when the slideshow started (so I will know how long it took the user to react on the presented item).  *Edit:* I must also record the time of the occurence of the special item.

I need to reduce any unpredictable lags that may occur as the application is running, so that the input processing is as realistic as possible, as well as to reduce any lags between the slides. Currently I am thinking of 3 approaches:

- Write a standard Windows Forms (GDI+) application.
- Write a WPF application
- Write a DirectX-enabled windows forms application that utilizes the [Tom Miller's Render loop](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/gametechnologiesgeneral/thread/17775f03-b243-43ae-b8ce-bf43646b2e4a/) concept (it is praised as effective in terms of performance).
- Something else that you might suggest

I must clarify that I will not use advanced display techniques, special effects or designed for the purpose 3D environments - just plain text slides in different fonts and colours, or images. Unfortunately I cannot cite my sources, but I have read that Windows Forms and GDI+ cannot provide me with the desired accuracy. So, is WPF going to provide me with a better solution? Do I need to use the render loop, or some other approach. I am not experienced in such type of performance requirements for desktop applications, and all advices will be appreciated greatly.

---

Comment: You should clarify your timing requirements (mostly for yourself) - "about 50ms" sounds very relaxed and probably can be achieved with any of the above mentioned technologies, "45-55ms" would require much more serious approach.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov,you are right, I did not mention the actual accuracy needed, but I think a tolerance of 10-15ms will be enough for me. I will edit my post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally love WPF, but I would be very wary of using it for this application. It is not going to have the same time precision as GDI+ or DirectX. There are all sorts things you'll have to work with like the DispatchTimer and it just wasn't build for something like this. WPF is a whole set of gigantic abstractions on top of graphics and the farther you get away from the metal, you're introducing potential problems. If you want to put a video projected on top of a 3D sphere inside a combobox then WPF is the way to go, but if you need accuracy/precision on the scale you're talking, WPF is not the answer. I don't know where you read that WPF will provide you with better accuracy, I can practically guarantee that it will not.

DirectX would most likely be the most accurate in ensuring that a picture is only displayed for 50ms at a time. But GDI+ would be a decent alternative solution because it will make it easier to deal with text from a programming perspective.

Another consideration, screen refresh rates. yikes. if you do the math most LCDs have a 5ms response rate which is 10% of your allotted time. That and they only display at 60Hz. If you're displaying 20 pictures per second (50ms per picture) it is only going to be on the screen for 3 refresh cycles.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I've gotten decent accuracy with GDI+ and p/invoking the windows multimedia timer.

Comment: Thank you for the informative response. I must make one clarification though - I did not read that WPF would provide better accuracy, but that it handles better user input, compared to WinForms (something with the win forms timer that is not very accurate, so I *assumed* WPF is better), and that it does not use GDI+, which I thought would be an advantage for task like mine. Still, it seems that WPF will not be the way to go, so I will consider a DirectX-oriented solution.

Answer (score 0):

50 msec isn't long. Maybe encode and play the slideshow as a video?

Comment: The items displayed will be randomly prepared at runtime depending on some entered by the user information, so it will not be possible to use a video.